# can redis do a leaderboard by categories + leaderboard encompassing all the categories

Tags: database, redis, data-modeling, rdbms, nosql

**Example**:

- Art ranking for categories: [ pictures, paintings, sculptures, ... ].

**Queries**:

- Top 10 pictures ?
- Sculptures with rank from 10 to 20 (pagination).
- Best art ? (combine all categories)

**To consider**

- Some arts have multiple categories. There are some sculptures that are paintings as well.
- There are a lot of art categories. Pictures, painting and sculpture is only a subset of them.

---

Redis seemed like a pretty good choice at first with sorted set for each art categories.

EG:

- zset:pictures
- zset:paintings
- ...

However, having a ranking for all categories combined requires another sorted set `zset:art`. This means that the score of each artistic item has to be updated in multiple places. This is a no-go.

I would like to be sure I'm thinking about this correctly, since I'm new to redis, before deciding to use a relational DB instead.

Comment: Why is the right solution a no go?

Comment: @ItamarHaber A "no go" is a strong word, I should have say that using a RDBMS would not require additional tables. I guess this is a trade off.

Comment: Exactly - denormalization is a common pattern in "NoSQL" databases